# Missing return in a function error - Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am extremely new to swift and this error keeps popping up.

It says `missing return in a function expected to return in UITableViewCell`

Code:
[image: My Code]

Any help... thanks so much

Comment: Don't add an image of the code, copy/paste into the question. Then select the code and chicl on the {} in the toolbar to make it display as code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a cell. The identifier is the one you have added in your Storyboard, mine is called "Cell" in this example.

```
let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Set the cell properties, for example

```
cell.textLabel.text = "Test"
```

And then return the cell

```
return cell
```

This method returns a cell at the given path, so this is the part were you add information for the cell. Read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) the get familiar with the UITableView class.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel.text = "Test
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: i am still confused please help...

Comment: Check the updated text.